# Python unpack like in PHP

Tags: python, unpack

In `PHP` I will do it like this:

```
$res = unpack('C*', "string");
```

And `$res` variable will be an array of size 6:

```
Array ( [1] => 115 [2] => 116 [3] => 114 [4] => 105 [5] => 110 [6] => 103 )
```

I want to do the same trick in `Python`. I tried this:

```
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> unpack("s","string")
```

But in this case I get an error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 1
```

I just wonder - why of length 1 if "s" format stands for string? And how can I implement the same thing, like in PHP?

Comment: You should probably explain what is your general goal because there is probably a better way to reach it.

Comment: In PHP I implemented a short code snippet that compares two documents and collects all the changes. If I have the initial version of the document and the history of all the changes (which is much less, than if I stored whole documents), then I can easily restore the document at any point in time. I decided to do the same thing in Python.

Comment: Oh, actually I think, I found a better solution based on `bytearray` function in Python.

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html ?

Comment: These methods are great! Thanks! But in my case, I think, handmade tiny methods will be sufficient

Comment: Or, I would say that these methods will be helpful for thorough investigation of changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `struct.unpack` format `s` means *"a string"*. By default it's a 1-char string, otherwise you would have to specify the length, e.g. `10s` for a 10-char string.

Anyway, **Python strings already behave like immutable arrays of characters**, so that you can do `s[3]` and obtaining the 4th (zero-based) char. If you need to explicitely explode the string into a dictionary (akin to PHP associative array), you could do:

```
 s = dict(enumerate("string"))
```

but I strongly recommend against doing so.

Comment: That works! Thank you, sir. I will upvote in 7 minutes.

Comment: @Jacobian I think you meant *I will* ***accept*** *in 7 minutes*

Comment: @Bhargav Rao. Yes, sure.